# Why is db:reset different from running all migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-migration

In section [Rails Database Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-migrations) of Ruby on Rails Guides, there is one line saying that

> The db:reset task will drop the database, recreate it and load the current
>   schema into it. This is not the same as running all the migrations.

Can anyone tell me where exactly they are different and why it is more error prone to replay the migration history?

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The schema file contains the current structure of your database. When you load it, you are guaranteed to have the exact schema in your db that is in the file. Migrations were designed to make incremental changes in the database. You may add a table, then some columns, and then remove the table in three separate migrations. There's no need to go through all this when the schema already knows that the table no longer exists.

On why they are error prone, I'm not totally sure. The one thing I can think of is that migrations can be used to make changes to data and not just the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Running `rake db:reset` will rebuild the structure of your database from `schema.db`, which essentially works as a cached version of your migrated database structure. Running all your migrations, on the other hand, applies the migrations one by one, which may include arbitrary code to accomodate for changes to the database (e.g. prepopulate an added counter cache column).

It *can* be more error prone to replay the migration history, since it is the product of changes to both the structure and data of the database. If the developers haven't been careful, it might not apply cleanly to a fresh environment (e.g. the migration assumes an old version of a model). On the other hand, `schema.db` can get out of sync if you edit a migration once you've migrated (a useful trick to avoid migration explosion during development). In that case, you need to run `rake db:migrate:reset`.